# How to Fetch Recording from Onvif using javascript

Tags: node.js, camera, fetch, recording, onvif

I am trying to fetch the recording from a vivotek camera using onvif interface. I tried using the function exportRecordedData using the documentation http://www.onvif.org/ver10/recording.wsdl but there was no result.

I am getting error

```
2022-06-10T04:39:59.728Z error: exportRecordedData(): Error: Error: ONVIF SOAP Fault: Operation Action Not Implemented. The requested action operation is not implemented by the device.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ExportRecordedData() implementations might be rare (I think I don't have them on TVT an Uniview).

The other option is using RTSP stream as returned by GetRecordings(). For TVT there is also alternative url: rtsp://IP:port/chID=1&date=2020-03-09&time=17:00:00&timelen=100&StreamType=main. Both TVT and Uniview work with Range in RTSP PLAY when using URL from GetRecordings(), but both also have some problems - TVT plays all recordings as one stream (at least I cannot distinguish them at the moment), Uniview plays only first recording from specified range.